# What is the difference between MoreLINQ's DistinctBy and Linq's GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, morelinq

I have two version of grouping by a list of items

```
List<m_addtlallowsetup> xlist_distincted = xlist_addtlallowsetups.DistinctBy(p => new { p.setupcode, p.allowcode }).OrderBy(y => y.setupcode).ThenBy(z => z.allowcode).ToList();
```

and groupby

```
List <m_addtlallowsetup>  grouped = xlist_addtlallowsetups.GroupBy(p => new { p.setupcode, p.allowcode }).Select(grp => grp.First()).OrderBy(y => y.setupcode).ThenBy(z => z.allowcode).ToList();
```

these two seemed to me that they are just the same, but there's gotta be a layman's explanation of their difference, their performance and disadvantages

Comment: Did you try to run both and compare results?

Comment: I mean `DistinctBy` and `GroupBy` gives completely different results. But `GroupBy + Select` give similar result to `DistinctBy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's review the `MoreLinq` APIs first, following is the code for `DistinctBy`:

### MoreLinq - DistinctBy

[Source Code](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs#L65)

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
            Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
        {
            if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
            if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));

            return _(); IEnumerable<TSource> _()
            {
                var knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
                foreach (var element in source)
                {
                    if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
                        yield return element;
                }
            }
       }
```

### Working

- Using `HashSet<T>` internally it just checks the first match and returns the first element of Type `T` matching the Key, rest are all ignored, since Key is already added to the HashSet
- Simplest way to get the first element pertaining to every unique Keyin the collection as defined by the `Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector`
- Use case is limited (Subset of what GroupBy can achieve, also clear from your code)

### Enumerable - GroupBy

([Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,f8c3dd2bd2281fcc))

```
public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector) {
            return new GroupedEnumerable<TSource, TKey, TElement>(source, keySelector, elementSelector, null);
        }

 internal class GroupedEnumerable<TSource, TKey, TElement> : IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>
    {
        IEnumerable<TSource> source;
        Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector;
        Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector;
        IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer;
 
        public GroupedEnumerable(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) {
            if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
            if (keySelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("keySelector");
            if (elementSelector == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("elementSelector");
            this.source = source;
            this.keySelector = keySelector;
            this.elementSelector = elementSelector;
            this.comparer = comparer;
        }
 
        public IEnumerator<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>> GetEnumerator() {
            return Lookup<TKey, TElement>.Create<TSource>(source, keySelector, elementSelector, comparer).GetEnumerator();
        }
 
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

### Working

- As it can be seen, internally use a `LookUp` data structure to group all the data for a given Key
- Provides flexibility to element and result selection via projection, thus would be able to meet lot of different use cases

---

### Summary

1. `MoreLinq - DistinctBy` achieves a small subset of what `Enumerable - GroupBy` can achieve. In case your use case is specific, use the More Linq API
2. For your use case, speed wise as the scope is limited `MoreLinq - DistinctBy` would be faster, since unlike `Enumerable - GroupBy`, `DistinctBy` doesn't first aggregate all data and then select first for each unique Key, MoreLinq API just ignores data beyond first record
3. If the requirement is specific use case and no data projection required then `MoreLinq` is a better choice.

This is a classic case in Linq, where more than one API can provide same result but we need to be wary of the cost factor, since `GroupBy` here is designed for much wider task than what you are expecting from `DistinctBy`

Answer (score 3):

### The Differences

`GroupBy` should result a 'group' that contains key (the grouping criteria) and its value. thats why you need to do `Select(grp => grp.First())` first.

You might suspect MoreLinq just provide shorthand of it. MoreLinq by [the source](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs#L71-L80), the `DistinctBy` is actually done **in memory** by picking every single item that is new for the `HashSet`. The [`HashSet#Add`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1_Add__0_) will add item and returns true if its a new element for the `HashSet`, then the `yield` will return the newly added element into the enumerable.

### Which One?

#### SQL Related

Based on the difference above, you could say doing `GroupBy` then project it with `Select` is much more safer approach as it can be translated into SQL command if you are using Entity Framework (or Linq2Sql, i suppose). Being able to be translated into SQL command is a great advantage to reduce the burden from your application and delegate operations to the Database Server instead.

However, you had to understand that `GroupBy` in the Entity Framework actually uses `OUTER JOIN` that considered as complex operation and on some cases it may cause your query being dropped immediately. Its pretty rare case, even the query i throw had lots of column, around four `GroupBy`s are used, a bunch of ordering and `Where`s.

#### Linq to Object

Roughly speaking when dealing with an already in memory enumerables. Running `GroupBy` then `Select` may end up have your enumerable need to be iterated by two operations. While directly using `DistinctBy` from MoreLinq can save some graces as it guarantees to be a single operation backed with HashSet as explained by **Mrinal Kamboj** answer with in depth analysis against the source code.

Comment: This is about `Linq2Object`, MoreLinq is a library dealing with Linq to objects translation, Linq2Sql / EF may not have a direct use case  out here, since it is not taking Expression anywhere to convert into a Sql as detailed in the answer

Comment: wah my bad, i simply dismissed the fact that the enumerable in question can be in memory already.. though you can have IEnumerable extension method run against [IQueryable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iqueryable?view=netframework-4.7.2) (a nice pitfall for most people - including me). i should never write an answer when i was not fully awake.

Comment: _HashSet#Add will return false if the item does not present on the HashSet_, **this statement shall be** _HashSet#Add will add element and return true if the item is not present on the HashSet_ since it will just add first unique key and reject the remaining. Surely +1 for the effort in explaining the Sql part though it may not always lead to efficient query and delegation as expected